# Eclipse Luna: "Unhandled event loop exception"

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

After I download Eclipse Luna 64 bit and installed ADT for Android, I face "Unhandled event loop exception" error, exactly when I entered the source code panel
here is full trace of this exception

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4467)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4356)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4327)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:476)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createHandle(Control.java:703)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label.createHandle(Label.java:199)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createWidget(Control.java:743)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.<init>(Control.java:111)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label.<init>(Label.java:101)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusLineContributionItem.fill(StatusLineContributionItem.java:182)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.SubContributionItem.fill(SubContributionItem.java:61)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.StatusLineManager.update(StatusLineManager.java:345)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.updateActivations(WorkbenchPage.java:302)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$17(WorkbenchPage.java:280)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$E4PartListener.partActivated(WorkbenchPage.java:202)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$3.run(PartServiceImpl.java:234)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.firePartActivated(PartServiceImpl.java:231)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:682)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:613)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.AbstractPartRenderer.activate(AbstractPartRenderer.java:106)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer$1.handleEvent(ContributedPartRenderer.java:61)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1085)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1070)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.setActiveControl(Shell.java:1453)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.WM_MOUSEACTIVATE(Shell.java:2334)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4654)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:339)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1626)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2075)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5037)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5037)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5037)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5037)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5037)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5037)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5037)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5037)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5037)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5037)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5037)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5037)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5037)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5037)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5037)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:339)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5037)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:339)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5037)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2443)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.BidiUtil.windowProc(BidiUtil.java:640)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.PeekMessageW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.PeekMessage(OS.java:3141)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3756)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1152)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1033)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

Task Manager > Processes > and End the task 'java.exe'

Restart 'java.exe' from your jre/bin

Restart eclipse

This worked for me.

You can also try modifying Xms and Xmx in eclipse.ini (in the eclipse installtion folder) to:
-Xms768m
-Xmx768m